# How to get single equation equivalent to any conjunction of equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Let's say we have a system of two equations. These may be any different equations without any constraints.

Is there a simple single rule to get another equation which would be an exact equivalent, which has exactly same solutions such as the system has?

Comment: **Resultant** get single equation with all roots of source system, but additional it can have excess roots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\bigwedge_i (a_i = b_i) \iff \sum_i (a_i - b_i)^2=0$$

Comment: This works for real solutions.  What about complex solutions?

Comment: Works there too: 0 is the only complex number whose square is 0.

Comment: $x=0 \wedge y=0$ has only one solution.  $x^2 + y^2 = 0$ also has $x=i, y=1$.

Comment: Yes, sorry. Of course you are right.

Comment: For complex the power is 4. The power is 2*(dimensions used)

Comment: Absolute also may be good if abs(i) is 1. 
Or 2*(+infinity).